# unable To Complete Command setup:di:compile

Tags: magento2, setup-upgrade, magento2.4.3.p1

unable to run command `php bin/magento setup:di:compile`
Showing Following error. Please Tell me

`1/9 [==>------------------]  11% 1 sec 131.0 MiBClass 'Liquid\AbstractBlock' not found#0 /home/737540.cloudwaysapps.com/braschathq/public_html/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php(444): include() #1 /home/737540.cloudwaysapps.com/braschathq/public_html/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php(322): Composer\Autoload\includeFile() #2 [internal function]: Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader->loadClass() #3 [internal function]: spl_autoload_call() #4 /home/737540.cloudwaysapps.com/braschathq/public_html/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Module/Di/Code/Reader/ClassesScanner.php(134): class_exists() #5 /home/737540.cloudwaysapps.com/braschathq/public_html/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Module/Di/Code/Reader/ClassesScanner.php(117): Magento\Setup\Module\Di\Code\Reader\ClassesScanner->includeClass() #6 /home/737540.cloudwaysapps.com/braschathq/public_html/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Module/Di/Code/Reader/ClassesScanner.php(87): Magento\Setup\Module\Di\Code\Reader\ClassesScanner->extract() #7 /home/737540.cloudwaysapps.com/braschathq/public_html/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Module/Di/App/Task/Operation/RepositoryGenerator.php(61): Magento\Setup\Module\Di\Code\Reader\ClassesScanner->getList() #8 /home/737540.cloudwaysapps.com/braschathq/public_html/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Module/Di/App/Task/Manager.php(56): Magento\Setup\Module\Di\App\Task\Operation\RepositoryGenerator->doOperation() #9 /home/737540.cloudwaysapps.com/braschathq/public_html/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Console/Command/DiCompileCommand.php(216): Magento\Setup\Module\Di\App\Task\Manager->process() #10 /home/737540.cloudwaysapps.com/braschathq/public_html/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php(255): Magento\Setup\Console\Command\DiCompileCommand->execute() #11 /home/737540.cloudwaysapps.com/braschathq/public_html/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(1009): Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run() #12 /home/737540.cloudwaysapps.com/braschathq/public_html/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(273): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand() #13 /home/737540.cloudwaysapps.com/braschathq/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Console/Cli.php(115): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun() #14 /home/737540.cloudwaysapps.com/braschathq/public_html/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(149): Magento\Framework\Console\Cli->doRun() #15 /home/737540.cloudwaysapps.com/braschathq/public_html/bin/magento(23): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() #16 {main}`

Comment: Please mention PHP version and Magento Version so easily idea for your issues and help to you

Comment: @BhaveshGodhani Php Version is 7.4

Answer (score 0):

Your code have dependencies on Magento\Framework\Search\Adapter\Mysql* classes.

Support of Mysql search adapter was deprecated in 2.3 and removed in 2.4.

Please review your code/customization and remove this dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

You magento setup miss package Liquid, install it manually:

```
vendor/bin/composer req "liquid/liquid"
```